# What software can I use to make 3D screenshots?

Tags: 3d, screenshot

For example, I'd like a 3D image of screenshots, similar to this one:

[image: test] (from WojoMarket's website)

Are there any ready made software in order to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so, as Rishab has said, your best bet is a mockup in photoshop. Lots of great places to find these, and my go-to is probably [Mockup World](http://www.mockupworld.co).

After a search I managed to find the exact one you're looking for though, so [here](http://graphicburger.com/isometric-perspective-mock-up/) you are.

Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

The Best software you can use to create this is Adobe Photoshop. However, if you search in google for **FREE PSD MOCK-UPS** you can find some sites that provide free PSD Mock-ups of course you need Photoshop to use the file. If you have some experience working in Photoshop then you can easily edit the Mockup files

You can also try search for PSD MOckups of Dashobard, Apps, etc on google depends on your need